# Styling first list items in nested lists

Tags: css, nested-lists

How to write a css selector that targets only the `<li>` elements that I have designated as *TARGET*?

```
<ul class="simple">
<li> TARGET
    <ul>
        <li> TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>

        <li>TARGET</li>

        <li>TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Forgot to add that I can't assign classes to my html, is generated with a static site generator. It has to be just with css, if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: and you don't have access to the html to give those li elements a class attribute? Or are you asking if css alone can target by content?

Comment: Exactly, I can't assign classes to the target elements. It has to be with that html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is a little more clear after your comment that you cannot affect the html.
Here is a fiddle showing my suggestion:

http://jsfiddle.net/knnzmutq/

```
.simple li{
    color:black;
}
.simple > li, .simple > li > ul > li{
    color:red;
}
```

The basic idea here is you first define the styles for normal li elements within `.simple` and then specifically overwrite for the children without affecting the nested elements by using the `>` selector. `.simple > li > ul > li` is saying start at simple class, then choose only the children li, then choose only the chldren ul of that first layer, then choose only the first children of that ul... convolutedly stated... but as you can see by the fiddle, the red color is not inherited by the last layer of li elements I have labeled as "not target"

Something to keep in mind is that this css is specific to your example. I don't know what your actual html looks like and whether or not your target behavior is exactly like this and nothing else. So clearly this is a basic example of dependent selectors and not necessarily a precise answer to your question.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was asking for. Thanks a lot Kai Qing.

Comment: Fair dues. Although this 'simple' example seems flawed quite a lot in its structure.

Comment: Maybe it's too much to ask, but do you think it would be possible a selector for the non TARGETS?

Comment: You could just add another layer of dependent selectors: `.simple > li > ul > li > ul > li`

Comment: @jbutler483 - oh I agree. For example, if OP just adds another li to the top layer and doesn't want that red then this example is not going to work. But as stated, this works for the example as is, not necessarily for whatever the actual html may be.

Comment: @javi: use this (it works on Kai's fiddle as well): **ul>li>ul>li>ul{background:blue;}**

Comment: @KaiQing: Without adding class/tags (even an a attribute) would have made this a LOT easier. I even have a funny feeling this could be for a navbar/something similar and this could be just the start of something extremely painful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to give your 'targets' a class, like:

```css
.target  {
  background-color:rgba(20,20,20,0.2);
}
.target > ul {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="simple">
<li class="target"> TARGET
    <ul>
        <li class="target"> TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>

        <li class="target">TARGET</li>

        <li class="target">TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You *could* use first child, although since you're using nested items, you'll be selecting all child elements as well

```css
ul:first-child  {
  
  background-color:rgba(20,20,20,0.2);

}
```

```html
<ul class="simple">
<li> TARGET
    <ul>
        <li> TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>

        <li>TARGET</li>

        <li>TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

```css
li{background:red;}

ul>li>ul>li>ul{background:blue;}
```

```html
<ul class="simple">
<li> TARGET
    <ul>
        <li> TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>

        <li>TARGET</li>

        <li>TARGET
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: That only styles the first target. I've also tried `ul > li:first-child`, but it didn't work as desired.

Comment: Which demo are you referring to? The first is more likely the one you're looking *for*

Comment: I can't assign classes to my html, is generated with a static site generator. It has to be just with css, if possible.

Comment: my last snippet (just added), i think will be the *closest* you'll get (whilst retaining re usability). But by the sounds of it, the 'generator' you're using is *pretty* bad, and should be steered well clear of!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to parse the content of the LI element without some scripting. A common approach to this is to assign a class to the relevant item.

```
<li class="target">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have a selector such as that as far as I know.

I would use jQuery for this.

Here's an example that uses jQuery to replace TARGET with a span containing a custom class around the word TARGET.

```
.targetClass {
   color: green;
   font-weight: bold;
}

$("ul.simple > li").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(/TARGET/g, "<span class='targetClass'>T</span>"); 
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/bnpgh4gp/1/